# K&R C example for malloc - moreroce pointer

Tags: c, memory, malloc

In K&R's The C programming language gives this implementation of malloc:

```
static Header base; /* empty list to get started */
static Header *freep = NULL; /* start of free list */
/* malloc: general-purpose storage allocator */
void *malloc(unsigned nbytes){
  Header *p, *prevp;
  Header *moreroce(unsigned);
  unsigned nunits;
  nunits = (nbytes+sizeof(Header)-1)/sizeof(header) + 1;
  if ((prevp = freep) == NULL) { /* no free list yet */
    base.s.ptr = freeptr = prevptr = &base;
    base.s.size = 0;
  }
  for (p = prevp->s.ptr; ; prevp = p, p = p->s.ptr) {
    if (p->s.size >= nunits) { /* big enough */
        if (p->s.size == nunits) /* exactly */
            prevp->s.ptr = p->s.ptr;
        else { /* allocate tail end */
            p->s.size -= nunits;
            p += p->s.size;
            p->s.size = nunits;
        }
        freep = prevp;
        return (void *)(p+1);
    }
    if (p == freep) /* wrapped around free list */
    if ((p = morecore(nunits)) == NULL)
    return NULL; /* none left */
  }
}
```

I'm confused about the line:
 Header *moreroce(unsigned);
What is this line for?  The pointer moreroce is not used for anything, and what does the (unsigned) mean?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is a typo for `morecore` ... also the `166` halfway down is odd

Comment: The book itself used moreroce in that line and not morecore.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how that 166 got there, it is not supposed to be there.

Comment: I guess this would be K&R 2nd edition... I think 1st ed. didn't use prototypes at all

Comment: archive.org has a scanned copy of the 1st edition (no prototypes): https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition  You can also see the typo in a scanned copy of the second edition: https://archive.org/stream/AnsiCProgrammingLanguage/Ansi%20C%20%20programming%20language#page/n163/mode/2up  Subsequent printings have the typo fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moreroce` is a typo.

```
Header *morecore(unsigned);
```

is a declaration of a function named `morecore` that takes a `unsigned` as an argument.